# discord.js embed mesage does not work on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, discord.js, pm2, raspberry-pi4

I wrote a short discord.js Bot, it does work well if i host it on my Windows PC.
But if i try to host the same code on my Raspberry Pi 4 with node.js and pm2 it does not show my "-help" command which uses embed message.
 All other commands work well on both my PC and on my Pi.
If i remove the part that embeds  the "-help" command it works again on my Pi. 
The following code works on Windows but not on my Pi.

```
    if(command === "help") {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Here is a list of all commands")
        .setColor(0x992d22)
        .setDescription("-capy\n-vibe\n-coinflip\n-jail")
    message.channel.send(embed)
    }
```

My node.js version on my PC is 14.16.1 and on my Pi it is 10.24.1
I did not get any errors as far as i can tell. 
How can i make the code work on my Raspberry Pi? Is the Problem the older node.js verison on my Pi?

Comment: Without any errors, can you describe how the code does not work on your Pi?

Comment: I have a couple of cammands that all work, howerve the the "-help" command uses embed and that one just doesnt work at all but i cant seem to find any error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Node v12+ to use djs v12, the problem is MessageEmbed uses some code that will break node v10 so just upgrade your node version